# Pojo desensitization in firebase android is behaving differently

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

This is my json

```
{
    "profile_min_salary": 10000,
    "profile_requirement_checklist": "Excel Aana Chahiye.",
    "tags": "central,12th pass,thoda english,good english,fluent      
         english,male,fresher,female"
}
```

Here is my Model

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
    getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)'

public class Job {

    @JsonProperty("profile_min_salary")
    private Integer profileMinSalary;

     @JsonProperty("profile_requirement_checklist")
    private String profileRequirementChecklist;

     @JsonProperty("tags")
    private String tags;

     public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public Integer getProfileMinSalary() {
        return profileMinSalary;
    }


    public void setProfileMinSalary(Integer profileMinSalary) {
        this.profileMinSalary = profileMinSalary;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }


    public String getProfileRequirementChecklist() {
        return profileRequirementChecklist;
    }

    public void setProfileRequirementChecklist(String profileRequirementChecklist) {
        this.profileRequirementChecklist = profileRequirementChecklist;
    }
}
```

This is my firebase code snippet

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Job job = dataSnapshot.getValue(Job.class);
                doOperationOnJob(job);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

But my class is getting only tags parameter else are null why ??

**While if I am writing this way it is working fine**

```
 @Override
 public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    String jsonData = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dataSnapshot.getValue());
       Job job= new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonData , Job.class);
       doOperationOnJob(job);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    Crashlytics.logException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

What should i change in code to make it work in first scenario ??
I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in your model to work with Firebase correctly.

```
private Integer profile_min_salary;
private String profile_requirement_checklist;
private String tags;
```

You don't actually need to set the `@JsonProperty` annotation to work with Firebase if the property names are the same.

So simply your POJO can look like this

```
public class Job {
    public Integer profile_min_salary;
    public String profile_requirement_checklist;
    public String tags;
}
```

As you've declared all the variables `public`, you can get them simply by creating an instance of your `Job` class (e.g. `Job mJob = new Job();`) and then `mJob.profile_min_salary`

Comment: isn't there any other trick to do so, just like property because my project is already using existing big Model I have posted only very small part of that

Comment: I would love to change all those models. I love simplicity. :D See the updated answer.

Comment: Its not about simplicity or complexity it about existing code. If you know anything It would help :) It is not ideal to change all existing code

Comment: Then I guess your second approach is better for you :)